# yocto splash screen not appearing

Tags: yocto, bitbake, syslinux

I'm making a yocto image which I'm booting from a usb stick using syslinux. There's a lot of boot output that I'd like to hide. From reading [the yocto docs](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#usingpoky-debugging-others) it looks like adding a splash screen should hide this. I have added `splash` to the `IMAGE_FEATURES`, but the splash screen doesn't appear, and the syslinux boot output is still visible. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Other suggestions on how to hide that boot output also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

To add splash screen into the image, in your `local.conf`, add

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " psplash"`

The psplash recipe is in `/poky/meta/recipes-core/psplash`.

Another option is to create `core-image-full-cmdline` which will have psplash in it.

**Edit**: If you want to modify the psplash screen, `git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/psplash`

have a `.png` image of yours with the same screen dimension

go to the psplash directory and find `make-image-header.sh`

`$./make-image-heaer.sh <your-image>.png POKY_IMG`

Note that I used `POKY_IMG` is because I want to replace the newly created psplash files in `poky/meta/recipes-core/psplash/files/psplash-poky-img.h`

There is also another psplash in `poky/meta-yocto/recipes-core/psplash`.  This one is `psplash_git.bbappend` which will override the one in `/poky/meta/recipes-core/psplash`.

In `psplash_git.bbappend`, after you have added your `my-splash-img.h` to the file directory, you could add `SPLASH_IMAGES = "file://my-splash-img.h;outsuffic=default"` for it to choose your splash image.

To change color of the background, bar, etc.  you will need to go to `${WORKDIR}/psplash/git/psplash-colors.h`.  The color is in hex.  After you have done, create a patch file to use it for next time compile.

Comment: I've added the line to the `local.conf`, and psplash appears in the image manifest, but still no splash screen appearing unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the customisation info, that'll come in handy pretty soon :)

Comment: What platform you are running psplash on?

Comment: @graugans Freescale i.MX6

Comment: @CharlesC. when your output device is configured that /dev/fb0 is the main screen then psplash should work out of the box on i.mx6. Please take a look at my [meta-udoo](https://github.com/graugans/meta-udoo/tree/krogoth/recipes-bsp/psplash) layer here I added a custom image for the splash screen. There is an [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BzSjhH7wPg) demonstrating this

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms like the [Amlogic S905 SOC](https://github.com/ssvb/xf86-video-fbturbo/issues/50) the OSD layer has a default transparency because it is intended to overlay a video. What is used for example in STB boxes. So you may have to set the transparency for each pixel

```
 From 01cf2069631609b6a9a17fe087cf96925f9ac546 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
 From: Christian Ege <k4230r6@gmail.com>
 Date: Sat, 20 Aug 2016 10:37:53 +0200
 Subject: [PATCH] Manage transparency to each 32 bit pixel in RGB888

 Otherwise we'll have a black screen instead of a boot splash

 Signed-off-by: Christian Ege <k4230r6@gmail.com>
 ---
  psplash-fb.c | 2 +-
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

 diff --git a/psplash-fb.c b/psplash-fb.c
 index 38cd6a4..6ca8006 100644
 --- a/psplash-fb.c
 +++ b/psplash-fb.c
 @@ -308,7 +308,7 @@ psplash_fb_plot_pixel (PSplashFB    *fb,
          break;
        case 32:
          *(volatile uint32_t *) (fb->data + off)
 -          = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue);
 +          = (0xFF << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue);
          break;

        case 16:
 -- 
 2.7.4
```

For more details check the following [github issue](https://github.com/ssvb/xf86-video-fbturbo/issues/50).